# How to overcome disadvantages of submitting form via ajax

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form which usually has a hash. I can submit the form the normal way and run the usual validation. If there are errors, the form re-renders and zend adds the usual errors. It seems that submitting forms with ajax (jQuery) means that I lose all this validation, which I'm sure was already addressed before. How do you get the same validation and handle the errors when doing ajax submissions?

I used to worry about the hash element, but what I discovered is that it seems to not matter for ajax forms submissions. So that's one out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling validation with an AJAX for is a two-step process. First you should incorporate comprehensive frontend validation. This should alert the user to issues prior to actually making the AJAX call.

Second include standard validation on the server. If this fails you can simply generate a 404 not found or 400 bad request because someone is attempting to send data without going through the frontend validation. Note that this could cause issues if you *need* to do server side validation for some components (duplicate email addresses, usernames, etc). In that case you can send the errors back in your desired format (JSON and XML are very common) and render them frontend.

Comment: Also, frontend validation depends on javascript being enabled. You can't always count on that, and giving a 404 based on that wouldn't exactly make for a good ux.

Comment: @Josh good point about the 404 not found. Haven't thought about this before as a way of handling those who played with the front end validation.

Comment: @Matthew I really don't know. I like his idea. What's the percentage of users today who don't have javascript enabled? Any stats? I hope they're less than 5%

Comment: @Matthew: That's what `<noscript>` tags are for. Also for forms that *absolutely require* JavaScript you can dynamically add the submit button. This way the form can't even be submitted unless JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: @Josh http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement. Also, some statistics I read said javascript being turned off in a browser was at 5% in 2008, so I imagine it's even less than that. I'm not saying you have to account for this, it depends on the situation. I'm just saying it's something to think about, and with something as simple as a web form, it's not too hard to take care of it both ways (server & client side)

Comment: @Matthew: I'm all for progressive enhancement, that's why I said you could also return errors in a JSON or XML format to the frontend. This is a touch more complicated though. Ideally you would build the form in plain HTML then add a binding to the submit event and handle it via JavaScript validation and AJAX submission. This way you would have a form that works fine with and without JavaScript.